# Group Function in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am working on a problem where I group a list into lots of lists based on a predicate using higher order functions.

```
val group: ('a -> 'a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list list
```

For example,

example 1:

```
# group sameLength ["phone", "iron", "man", "mouse", "ice"];;

-: string list list = 

[["iron"; "ice"] ; ["man"; "mouse"]; ["phone"]]
```

example 2:

```
# group (sameMod 2) [-5; -4; -3; -2; -1; 0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5];;

-: int list list = [[-4; -2; 0; 2; 4]; [-5; -3; -1; 1; 3; 5]]
```

This is what I have now but this is not behaving correctly

```
let group p = List.fold_right (fun x (tlst, flst) -> if p x then (x:: tlst) else (tlst, x::flst)) tlst List.@ (group p flst)

(* trying to output tlst based on predicate and append onto group function (flst) *)
```

Does anyone have any pointers to share? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I want to output list of lists. It could be 1 list, 2 lists, 3 lists or n lists based on the predicate.

Comment: Got confused. For `group sameLength ["phone", "iron", "man", "mouse", "ice"];;`, is `[["iron"; "ice"] ; ["man"; "mouse"]; ["phone"]]` correct output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, we need to be aware that if `f x y = true` and `f x z = true` then `f y z = true`.

So what we can do is

1. get an element `x` from the list
2. then partition the list into `l1` and `l2`. In `l1`, all elements for `f x` are `true`. all elements in `l2` are `false` to `x`
3. continue to group l2

Worst case time complexity is `O(N^2)`, when all elements are `false` to each other.

---

```
let group f l =
  let rec grouping acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | hd::tl ->
      let l1,l2 = List.partition (f hd) tl in
      grouping ((hd::l1)::acc) l2
  in 
  grouping [] l

let same_len s1 s2 = String.length s1 = String.length s2

let same_mod m x y = x mod m = y mod m

let l = ["phone";"iron";"man";"mouse";"ice"]

# group same_len l;;
- : string list list = [["man"; "ice"]; ["iron"]; ["phone"; "mouse"]]
```

Comment: What happens if the condition fails for all the elements in `l`? The `l2` list will be equal to `l` and thus result in an infinite loop, since the function will always be called with the same input list (`l` = `l2`).

Comment: @Rizo Yeah, you are right. It is a bug. Will fix it now.